# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception cloning app from git

Tags: android, git, gradle, build

i'm trying to run app what i found from git 
so i'm try to cloning this in my android studio 
but the problem is this is strange, because when i made the app by myself
there is two of build.gradel first Project, second Module:app
but this is just have

this is what i want to clon and want to run 
https://github.com/mdy0501/Airbnb

but it's not working 
when i push the run button 
it show

[when i push the button 'run'][1]

what should i do? 
if i want to run that app in my android studio

**This is console showing to me**

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
   > Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/C:/Users/bon300-36/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.pom
         file:/C:/Users/bon300-36/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.jar
         file:/C:/Users/bon300-36/AndroidStudioProjects/Airbnb/Airbnb/sdk-manager/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.jar
     Required by:
         project :app
         project :app > com.android.support:design:25.3.1
   > Could not find com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/C:/Users/bon300-36/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/27.0.2/cardview-v7-27.0.2.pom
         file:/C:/Users/bon300-36/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/27.0.2/cardview-v7-27.0.2.jar
         file:/C:/Users/bon300-36/AndroidStudioProjects/Airbnb/Airbnb/sdk-manager/com/android/support/cardview-v7/27.0.2/cardview-v7-27.0.2.jar
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/C:/Users/bon300-36/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/27.0.2/support-v4-27.0.2.pom
         file:/C:/Users/bon300-36/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/27.0.2/support-v4-27.0.2.jar
         file:/C:/Users/bon300-36/AndroidStudioProjects/Airbnb/Airbnb/sdk-manager/com/android/support/support-v4/27.0.2/support-v4-27.0.2.jar
     Required by:
         project :app
         project :app > com.android.support:design:25.3.1
         project :app > com.android.support:design:25.3.1 > com.android.support:transition:25.3.1
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/C:/Users/bon300-36/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/27.0.2/support-annotations-27.0.2.pom
         file:/C:/Users/bon300-36/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/27.0.2/support-annotations-27.0.2.jar
         file:/C:/Users/bon300-36/AndroidStudioProjects/Airbnb/Airbnb/sdk-manager/com/android/support/support-annotations/27.0.2/support-annotations-27.0.2.jar
     Required by:
         project :app > com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1
         project :app > com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1 > com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1
         project :app > com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1 > com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.3.1
         project :app > com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0 > com.github.bumptech.glide:gifdecoder:4.0.0
         project :app > com.android.support:design:25.3.1 > com.android.support:transition:25.3.1
   > Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/C:/Users/bon300-36/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.pom
         file:/C:/Users/bon300-36/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.jar
         file:/C:/Users/bon300-36/AndroidStudioProjects/Airbnb/Airbnb/sdk-manager/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.jar
     Required by:
         project :app > jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.2.3
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/C:/Users/bon300-36/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/27.0.2/support-annotations-27.0.2.pom
         file:/C:/Users/bon300-36/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/27.0.2/support-annotations-27.0.2.jar
         file:/C:/Users/bon300-36/AndroidStudioProjects/Airbnb/Airbnb/sdk-manager/com/android/support/support-annotations/27.0.2/support-annotations-27.0.2.jar
     Required by:
         project :app > com.baoyz.pullrefreshlayout:library:1.2.0
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/C:/Users/bon300-36/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/27.0.2/support-v4-27.0.2.pom
         file:/C:/Users/bon300-36/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/27.0.2/support-v4-27.0.2.jar
         file:/C:/Users/bon300-36/AndroidStudioProjects/Airbnb/Airbnb/sdk-manager/com/android/support/support-v4/27.0.2/support-v4-27.0.2.jar
     Required by:
         project :app > com.baoyz.pullrefreshlayout:library:1.2.0
   > Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/C:/Users/bon300-36/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.pom
         file:/C:/Users/bon300-36/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.jar
         file:/C:/Users/bon300-36/AndroidStudioProjects/Airbnb/Airbnb/sdk-manager/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.0.2/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.jar
     Required by:
         project :app > com.tsengvn:typekit:1.0.1








  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wGfC.png
```

Comment: You can try this my solution